# How does Clojure's reduce function work to reverse a list but not a vector

Tags: clojure

I was looking at ways to reverse a collection using Clojure without using the `reverse` function and stumbled upon this solution.

```
(reduce conj '() [1 2 3 4 5]) => (5 4 3 2 1)
```

I have read the Clojure api with regard to how reduce works but am still baffled as to how it is working in this instance.

Also I have found if I were to pass a vector as the third argument instead of a list ie:

```
(reduce conj [] [1 2 3 4 5]) => [1 2 3 4 5]
```

I seem to get back the same vector.

I was wondering if anybody could give me a brief explanation as to to how `reduce` is working in both instances.

Also I have found this method also reverses a vector:

```
(into () [1 2 3 4]) => (4 3 2 1) ; ???
```

Comment: `reduce` isn’t doing anything weird here. Compare the results of `(conj '(1) 2)` and `(conj [1] 2)` to verify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The doc string says: conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs 'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item). The 'addition' may happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.

For a vector, the natural place to add is the end.  For a list, the natural place to add is the front (as with 'cons').